# Problems with South/Django: not recognizing the Django App

Tags: python, macos, migration, django-south

I've got a Django project on my machine and when I try to use South to migrate the data schema, I get several odd errors. Example:

> $ python manage.py convert_to_south thisLocator
>
> /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/registration/models.py:4: DeprecationWarning: the sha >module is deprecated; use the hashlib module instead
> import sha
> /Users/cm/code/thisLocator/../thisLocator/batches/models.py:6: DeprecationWarning: the md5 >module is deprecated; use hashlib instead
> import md5
>
> *There is no enabled application matching 'thisLocator'.*

I've followed the South documentation. Settings.py has it in the installed apps, I can run import south from the manage.py shell. Everyone else on my team is calling the app thisLocator.

Am I doing something really stupid?

Comment: For anyone else experiencing this error, be sure to check that your app is in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py!

Answer (score 3):

> Am I doing something really stupid?

Well, let's start with the "is it plugged in" questions:

- Is your project directory in your Python path?
- Are you running `python manage.py` and not, say, `python some/path/i/am/omitting/manage.py`? (This is a great way to *not* have the project in the Python path.)
- What is the output of `./manage.py syncdb`?  (I use ./manage.py instead of `python manage.py` just in case they refer to different pythons.)

Comment: Mike, thanks for the response. I ended up nailing it. The app is organized in a somewhat unconventional way with multiple subdirectories. I was able to find the different models.py in various files and cobble together the migration.

Comment: Well, you solved *my* problem! I was in the wrong directory >.<

Comment: I've taken to putting `sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))` in my `manage.py` (and my `django.wsgi` and anything else that runs the project).  That way, I can run it from everywhere.

Comment: `+1` for "is it plugged in"